# Scala (method / function).hashCode static value?

Tags: scala, lambda

I' was curious if the hashCode() function returns always the same value for a lambda or something in Scala?

My tests have shown to me some static value that does not change even over builds. Is this intended behavior or may it change in future?

If this was some static behavior it would help me a lot building my library.

**EDIT:**

Let's take this source code:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = (s: String) => 1
    val y = (s: String) => 2

    println(x.hashCode())
    println(y.hashCode())
  }
}
```

It's output on console is for me always `1792393294` and `226170135`.

What I'm currently doing is implementing a parser combinator library which I implemented in several languages. And I need to know when wrapper classes are the same (e.g. the underlying functions are the same) so I can implement something like a call stack, which I need to parse as far as possible on failure but prevent endless recursion on error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean for 2 instances of identical lambdas?  Can you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @BenReich I updated my question with a sample and a concrete use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default implementation for `hashCode` (at least in the Oracle JVM) is in terms of the (initial) memory address of that particular object. So if your program has constructed exactly the same sized objects in exactly the same order before constructing that object, it will in practice return the same value every time.

But this is not at all reliable; most programs do not do exactly the same things every time they run. As soon as you're doing something like responding to user input, that perfect reproducibility will disappear - e.g. maybe you sometimes add enough entries to a `HashMap` to trigger an enlargement of the table, and sometimes not. And if you construct the same value later in the program, it will of course have a different address; try doing

```
val z = (s: String) => 1
```

and observe that it will have a different `hashCode` from `x`. Not to mention that the numbers may well be different across different JVMs, different versions of the same JVM, or even when the same JVM is launched with a different `-Xms` setting.

Computers are often a lot more deterministic in practice than in theory. But this is not the kind of thing that's specified to happen, and certainly not something to rely on in your programs.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! As long as it's the same ID in the same run I can live with it.

Comment: If you're using it as some kind of "unique ID", remember that `hashCode` is allowed to return the same value for different objects (but not different values for the same objects); if two objects have the same `hashCode` you should still use `equals` to check that they're "really equal".